# Formatting not working in 4gl [ USING clause ]

Tags: informix, 4gl

I was trying to format the output variable as follows:

#### Scenario 1:

```
LET msg = "Roopesh Majeti here "
           Empno Using "&&&&&"
Call Logmsg(msg)
```

In this scenario, the empno get formatted to 5 digits [ I should say spaces ] and gets displayed.

#### Scenario 2:

```
Let c_check = "&&"
Let msg ="Roopesh Majeti here"
          Empno using c_check
Call Logmsg(msg)
```

Here, my expectation is that, whatever is the value of c_check [ say 10 &'s ] then the empno should be formatted to 10 positions/spaces.

But it's not working as expected.

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Guys, I was able to resolve it. I was missing "CLIPPED" keyword that will truncate the extra spaces. Thanks to all, for giving valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what you do get, which makes it hard to know how it is  not working.

You have some minor syntax errors, missing the commas after the constant strings.

You don't show the declaration of `msg` or `c_check`; could the problem be that the message is being truncated?

What do you get when you use:

```
DISPLAY "<<", msg CLIPPED, ">>"
DISPLAY "<<", msg,         ">>"
```

You should be able to show us a complete program like this, and its output:

```
MAIN

    DEFINE msg      CHAR(64)
    DEFINE c_check  CHAR(20)
    DEFINE empno    INTEGER

    LET empno = 12345
    LET msg = "Roopesh Majeti here ", empno Using "&&&&&"
    DISPLAY "<<", msg CLIPPED, ">>"
    DISPLAY "<<", msg,         ">>"

    LET empno = 987654321
    LET c_check = "&&"
    LET msg ="Roopesh Majeti here", empno USING c_check
    DISPLAY "<<", msg CLIPPED, ">>"
    DISPLAY "<<", msg,         ">>"

END MAIN
```

Comment: You got it Jonathan.. I forgot to place CLIPPED, which is making to display the string, equal to its length and not getting stripped, displaying only actual data.